# Apache Cordova Build Android Error

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

**Hi everyone, I am having trouble finding solutions to this error:**

```
// THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT I ISSUED: 
F:\MyRepo\storeApp>cordova build android

// Repsonse
ANDROID_HOME=F:\Cordova\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The Error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ': classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.

BUILD FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.24.209] failed: Read timed out
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Read timed out
```

**I have installed all necessary requirements:**

```
 F:\MyRepo\storeApp>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-17,android-24,android-25,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24
Gradle: installed
```

**I just can't seem to find a solution to this, any help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: why your `ANDROID_HOME` is located to `android-sdk-windows`? I think it has to be `set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk`

Comment: Hi! I have set it already in the Environment Variables.

Comment: and that was just the name of the directory of my downloaded SDK...

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563345 ?  Check also the other posts in the related tab on the right.

Comment: @jcllevado Are you behind firewall? looks like connection time out issue

Comment: Hi @GrishaLevit I'll check that out! thanks..

Comment: Hi @Gandhi... I am using some proxy.. so this might be an issue.. i'll tend to that too.. thanks..

Comment: @jcllevado keep me posted so that I can post the answer

Comment: I solved it!! The problem is with the proxy that I am using... I just use a non-proxy network and it worked...